# internet explorer text input onkeyup char 13

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

the onkeyup event does not seem to be called for IE8/IE9 (I don't know about 10) when we press the enter button on an input box, if in the page there is a button element.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onku(id, e) {
    var keyC = 0;
    keyC = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += keyC + "<br>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="submit" >Test Button</button>
<input type="text" maxlength="5" onkeyup="onku(id, event);">
<br>
<div id="mydiv"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

so for every input onku() will be called, but not on ENTER ( keyC = 13 ).
Now, if i remove the

```
<button type="submit" >Test Button</button>
```

button, it will fire. Anyone knows why ?

No other browser has the problem.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssmpM/

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the `type="submit"` and it worked.